# Merge libgdx game with android studio project

Tags: android

I have created a libgdx game and an android studio project. I want to be able to open my game from the application using a game button. How can I add the game to the android project?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create your libgdx project.
2. Import and open it with Android Studio (as Stragulus recommended and you already did)

Now, you need these classes on your modules (some will appear automatically):

a) android

- AndroidLauncher (to start your game)
- MainActivity (to start your android app, this will be your launcher class)
- other classes you need

b) core

- MyGame
- CoreAndroidInterface (if you need comunication from your game to android)
- other classes you need

On your AndroidManifest.xml, you have to change the launcher:

(between Aplication tags code)

```
        <activity
            android:name="com.ongngo.game.AndroidLauncher"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="yourchoice..."
       android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ongngo.game.MainActivity" //Your launch activity, not necessarily MainActivity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="yourchoice..."
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

AndroidLauncher.kt or java:

```
class AndroidLauncher : AndroidApplication() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val config = AndroidApplicationConfiguration()
        config.useAccelerometer = false
        config.useCompass = false
        initialize(MyGame(MainActivity.VARIABLE_YOU_WANT_TO_UPDATE, MainActivity.coreAndroidInterface), config) //You pass your data to the game
    }
}
```

MainActivity.kt:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {...
companion object {//I need to see this from AndroidLauncher
        var coreAndroidInterface: CoreAndroidInterface? = null
        var VARIABLE_YOU_WANT_TO_UPDATE: Int? = null 
    }
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
...
        coreAndroidInterface = object : CoreAndroidInterface {
            override fun updateData(data: Int) { //you retrieve data from the game
                MainActivity.VARIABLE_YOU_WANT_TO_UPDATE = data
            }
        }
...

   override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        when (v?.id) {
            R.id.play_MyGame ->{ //your Button id to start the game
                    val playGame = Intent(this.context, AndroidLauncher::class.java)
                    startActivity(playGame)
            }
...
```

CoreAndroidInterface (only necessary if you need to retrieve data from your game)

```
interface CoreAndroidInterface {
    fun updateData(data : Int)
}
```

MyGame.java:

```
public class MyGame extends Game implements ApplicationListener {
...
public static int DATA = 0;
//constructor
    public MyGame(int data, CoreAndroidInterface coreAndroidInterface) {
        this.DATA = data;//data comes from the android side
        this.coreAndroidInterface = coreAndroidInterface;
    }

//I modify DATA 

//you can use the interface method at any point of your game when necessary, to get your data back to android.
    @Override
    public void pause() {
        super.pause();
        SavedDataManager.getInstance().save();
        coreAndroidInterface.updateData(DATA);
    }
```

This is my first game, so keep in mind I am just a begginer.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to do exactly this thing two weeks ago, and found it to be impossible. Well, it's probably possible with a lot of digging into the project setup files, but I didn't find it worth my time.

I resorted to doing a new [LibGDX project creation](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Project-Setup-Gradle), followed by an import as new project in Android Studio by [importing the build.gradle file](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-and-Intellij-IDEA). From there on, drop the code from the existing Android Studio project into your new project.

Comment: Thank for the answer!! I imported my libgdx project as a new project in Android studio. Should the two projects have the same package and do I add the manifest file of the existing project? Do I replace it with the manifest of the new project and add to it the android launcher activity?

Comment: I kept the Manifest file LibGDX created and added all the code from the other project using the same package names into the core/src folder of the new LibGDX project. I assume your new LibGDX project will launch the game using the LibGDX's main Game class. You will have to port over the main class from your existing project to use the LibGDX scaffolding though. If you need help with that you'll have to be a little more specific about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I want my android project (other than the game) main menu activity to launch the LibGDX's main Game class using a game button.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is rather late but you could check the video explaining the procedure. I did it following a tutorial as specified in the description :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xXgCU4ZuTyE

Comment: From Review: Hi, while links are a great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)